# Make a class icon (phone) clickable

Tags: html, css, mobile, hyperlink, font-awesome

I am currently using some font-awesome to embed some image like resources into my site.

I would like to create a hyperlinked icon that can be clicked to prompt making a call. I currently have the icon floated top right but I am unable to make this usable. I only want the icon to be the hyperlink and do not want any text surrounding this. I want to use the font awesome icon instead of an image so that i can be scaled up if the user zooms in.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>DB Plumbing | About</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/3a2264e344.js"></script>
  <script src="html9shiv.js"></script>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="wrench.png"/>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1,initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="desciption" content = "Darran Brady Plumbing">
  <meta name="keywords" content = "Plumbing, Boilers, Showers, Central Heating, Kitchens, Bathrooms, Installations, Landlord Services, Horsham, West Sussex, Sussex,Barns Green, Billingshurst,Broadbridge Heath,Christ's Hospital, Clemsfold, Copsale,Colgate,Cowfold, Faygate, Handcross, Horsham, Itchingfield, Kingsfold,Lambs Farm,Lower Beeding,Mannings Heath, Maplehurst, Monks Gate, Nuthurst, Partridge Green, Pease Pottage, Roffey, Rowhook, Rusper, Rudgwick, Southwater, Slinfold, Warnham ">
  <meta name = "author" content ="DB, Darran, Brady, Darran Brady">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script>
function myFunction() {
 var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
 if (x.className === "topnav") {
 x.className += " responsive";
 } else {
 x.className = "topnav";
 }
}
</script>
</head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:200%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </header>

<div class="container">
      <div class="dark">
            <div class="callus"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" ></i><a href="www.bbc.co.uk"></a>          </div>

            <h2>Our Story | Our Family</h2>
            </div>
            </div>

<section id="main">
      <div class="container">

        <article id="main-col">
          <h1 class="page-title">Our Journey</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius auctor lacus nec feugiat. Phasellus sit amet ex ipsum. Praesent pharetra tincidunt tempor. Etiam velit eros, dapibus eget porta in, lacinia et magna. Nam eget eros non orci consectetur congue at ac augue. Proin eget arcu in enim feugiat ultricies. Curabitur maximus metus nec metus pretium viverra at et orci. Integer hendrerit ante ut placerat cursus.
          </p>
          <p class="dark">
Aliquam eget pharetra diam. Nulla placerat lorem at turpis tempor, vel ultrices dui tincidunt. Proin quis egestas lorem. Mauris vehicula lectus odio, sit amet dictum justo feugiat a. Praesent id dictum lacus. Sed ullamcorper id erat ut dictum. Fusce porttitor lorem sapien, in aliquet sapien convallis et. Donec nec mauris nulla. Curabitur cursus semper odio, et hendrerit ante. Nunc at cursus ante. Maecenas gravida ligula ut efficitur suscipit. Nulla id turpis varius, pretium nunc sed, fermentum sem. Sed lacinia nunc non interdum pellentesque.
          </p>
        </article>

        <aside id="sidebar">
          <div class="dark">
            <h3>What We Do</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius auctor lacus nec feugiat. Phasellus sit amet ex ipsum. Praesent pharetra tincidunt tempor. Etiam velit eros, dapibus eget porta in, lacinia et magna</p>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>
 <footer>
      <p>Darren Brady Plumbing Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Put a `pointer-event: none` style on the i-tag. It will let pass your click action to the a-tag. And wrap it within the a-tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the `<i>` tag in a hyperlink `<a>` tag. All of the child elements of the `<a>` will take you to the hyperlink on click.

```
<div class="callus"><a href="www.bbc.co.uk"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" ></i></a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Fontawsome to show the icone and using [`href="tel:911"`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwjWo7r72NDXAhWDuBQKHSCZBEoQFgguMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fthe-current-state-of-telephone-links%2F&usg=AOvVaw3w8sNLPT3fcFWUvgV-I4nc) to creat the phone call see code snippet

```css
.callus {
position:fixed;
right:10px;
top:0px;
width:30px;
height:30px;
cursor:pointer;
}
.callus i {
color:green;
transition:all 1s ease-out
}
.callus:hover i {
transform:scale(1.3);
opacity:0.8;
transition:all 1s ease-out
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1><span class="highlight">DB</span> Plumbing</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
            <li class="active"><a href="home9.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about9.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="services9.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="coverage9.html">Coverage</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact9.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="icon">
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:200%;" onclick="myFunction()">☰</a></li></ul>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </header>

<div class="container">
      <div class="dark">
            <div class="callus"><a href="tel:911"><i class="fa fa-phone fa-3x" ></i></a><a href="www.bbc.co.uk"></a>          </div>

            <h2>Our Story | Our Family</h2>
            </div>
            </div>

<section id="main">
      <div class="container">

        <article id="main-col">
          <h1 class="page-title">Our Journey</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius auctor lacus nec feugiat. Phasellus sit amet ex ipsum. Praesent pharetra tincidunt tempor. Etiam velit eros, dapibus eget porta in, lacinia et magna. Nam eget eros non orci consectetur congue at ac augue. Proin eget arcu in enim feugiat ultricies. Curabitur maximus metus nec metus pretium viverra at et orci. Integer hendrerit ante ut placerat cursus.
          </p>
          <p class="dark">
Aliquam eget pharetra diam. Nulla placerat lorem at turpis tempor, vel ultrices dui tincidunt. Proin quis egestas lorem. Mauris vehicula lectus odio, sit amet dictum justo feugiat a. Praesent id dictum lacus. Sed ullamcorper id erat ut dictum. Fusce porttitor lorem sapien, in aliquet sapien convallis et. Donec nec mauris nulla. Curabitur cursus semper odio, et hendrerit ante. Nunc at cursus ante. Maecenas gravida ligula ut efficitur suscipit. Nulla id turpis varius, pretium nunc sed, fermentum sem. Sed lacinia nunc non interdum pellentesque.
          </p>
        </article>

        <aside id="sidebar">
          <div class="dark">
            <h3>What We Do</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec varius auctor lacus nec feugiat. Phasellus sit amet ex ipsum. Praesent pharetra tincidunt tempor. Etiam velit eros, dapibus eget porta in, lacinia et magna</p>
          </div>
        </aside>
      </div>
    </section>
```